# Disk with corrupted partition table unable to dd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

The drive is a 8TB drive, have been using it for a few years, but now on Windows it says it's 2TB unallocated (the whole disk it says it's only 2TB and whole disk unallocated) and have to be initialised. In Ubuntu, Gparted keeps getting error when reading it and also shows that the whole disk is only 2TB and it's unallocated. `fdisk -l` doesn't show it, `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` says input/output error. I guess it's the partition table that is corrupted.

Currently I'm running testdisk quick scan, with every cylinder at read error (currently still at cylinder

Any other way to recover the disk, or at least make a clone so that when I attempt to recover I won't do any real damage to the disk?

Answer (score 2):

If the total disk size is reported incorrectly, then there's something very wrong with disk's circuitry. Simply transplanting the circuit board from another identical disk won't work, because disks have baked-in maps of factory bad sectors and these are specific for every unit. You need to get a new disk and restore your data from backups.